# Regex: skip the first match of a character in group?

Tags: python, regex

From this string

```
s = 'stringalading-0.26.0-1'
```

I'd like to extract the part `0.26.0-1`. I can think of various ways to achieve this, using split or a regular expression using a pattern like this

```
pattern = r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\-\d+'
```

I also tried to use a group of characters, like so:

```
pattern = r'[.\-\d]+'
```

This gives me:

```
In [30]: re.findall(pattern, s)
Out[30]: ['-0.26.0-1']
```

So I wondered: is it possible to skip the first occurrence of a character in a group, in this case the first occurrence of `-`?

Comment: Your first regex works correctly, but I'd advise not to use any regex here if you just need to split the string into 2 parts with the first hyphen. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it possible to to skip the first occurrence of a character in a group, in this case the first occurrence of -?

**NO**, because when matching, the regex engine processes the string from left to right, and once the matching pattern is found, the matched chunk of text is written to the match buffer. Thus, either write a regex that only matches what you need, or post-process the found result by stripping unwanted characters from the left.

I think you do not need a regex here.  You can [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the string with `-` and pass the *maxsplit* argument set to `1`, then just access the second item:

```
s = 'stringalading-0.26.0-1'
print(s.split("-", 1)[1])   # => '0.26.0-1'
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/AHcUJZ)

Also, your first regex [works well](http://ideone.com/Nxib4H):

```
import re
s = 'stringalading-0.26.0-1'
pat = r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+-\d+'
print(re.findall(pat, s)) # => ['0.26.0-1']
```

Answer (score 3):

Do:

```
-(.*)
```

and get captured group 1.

**Example:**

```
In [9]: s = 'stringalading-0.26.0-1'

In [10]: re.search(r'-(.*)', s).group(1)
Out[10]: '0.26.0-1'
```

Comment: Nice solution! group 1 is everything after the first ``-``, right?

Comment: @LarsVegas `.*` is everything after `-` and we have captured it using `()` around.

Comment: But the question remains: is it possible to skip the first occurrence of a certain string in a group like in my example?

Comment: @LarsVegas With captured group, we are outputing only the desired portion within `()`, so if the first occurrence of a token is outside `()`, it will be ignored anyway.